# Firebase Console manually insert object to value

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to manually add new data to firebase. I found [this](http://mariechatfield.com/tutorials/firebase/step2.html) tutorial but this is only for depth 1. How can I add something like this ?

```
 roles: {
    "ajda4a684fawefae" : ["role1", "role2"],
    "as87awda74w8wa86" : ["role1", "role3"]
  }
```

Main problem is to put part in `{}` to value.

---

**UPDATE**

---

I have found solution. It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Please if you down vote, say why

Comment: Not the downvoter. But it would help if you: 1) tag the question with the programming language you're using, 2) include a piece of the code you've already tried. Both improve the chances of somebody helping, and reduce the changes of being downvoted.

Comment: I said "manualy " not using any language .... I even included example of simple manual add. Is it so hard to understand?

Comment: Yes, it is hard to understand. It's helpful to include more clear details in questions. It appears that by *manually* you mean to add more data via the *Firebase console*. The instructions linked in the question are pretty darn specific - I just walked through them and was able to add data and see the results per the link. What part are you getting stuck on? As a quick side note, that tutorial is based on using Array's; IMO PLEASE don't use arrays in Firebase, they can be very limiting.

Comment: ok thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I just added a structure like that in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/) of one of my projects

[image: edit mode of Firebase database]

I didn't know that you can enter arrays as literals. When I needed them before, I added them by entering explicit numeric child keys (which is how the database ends up storing them).

Comment: For future reference: Click on the small + symbol on the right-hand side to add a child property to the object.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer is likely a few years too late, but in case it helps anyone else, you just need to use valid json. Keys need to be in quotes, string values need to be in quotes, while numbers and booleans should not be. See my example!
[image]